# Can a Flask app dynamically connect to a SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**Background:**

I am creating a database management micro-API at work. We have multiple SQL Servers with many databases attached to each server.

**The Goal:**

In the UI (already built), the user selects a server from a list. This will send a request to the API which would query the names of all the databases on that server and return them in the response.

**The Problem:**
A `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` string needs to be created before the Flask app is run (at least in the way I have my app configured). To the best of my knowledge, this string can't be updated during runtime. How can I re-architect my app to do what I want?

Any comments or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Minimal, reproducible example of my current implementation which requires a `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` string to be created before the Flask app is run:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from omegaconf.dictconfig import DictConfig

db = SQLAlchemy()


def init_extensions(app: Flask) -> Flask:
    db.init_app(app)
    return app


def register_blueprints(app: Flask) -> Flask:
    pass


def init_app(config: DictConfig) -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__.split(".")[0])
    app.config.update(
        DEBUG=config.debug,
        SECRET_KEY=config.secret_key,
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=config.database_uri,
    )

    app = init_extensions(app)
    app = register_blueprints(app)

    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = init_app(config)
    app.run(host=config.server.host, port=config.server.port, debug=config.debug)
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/binds/

Comment: An outline of the solution I've used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738948/5400385)